# How to train and practice Wifi attack?

Tags: penetration-test, wifi, wep

I've just got a quick question about how to train Wifi attacks (WEP,WPA,etc...), I can't really do this on my own Wifi, it would be terrible if someone broke into it for example, so do you guys know a way to do that, maybe creating a virtual wifi or something, I don't know.

Comment: Buy a cheap or used router and you can set it up for different scenarios and practice against that.

Comment: Yeah but I will still be accessible from outside. It doesn't really change the problem.

Comment: You can use a router and create a wifi network with no other devices on it and without an internet connection. I am not understanding the problem with that?

Comment: You will soon get bored practicing these attacks. WPA2-PSK with strong password and WPS disabled is currently unbreakable.

Comment: Yeah I agree, most of people are using WPA2-PSK now that it's put by default anyway, but I've got the need to try it just once.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply buy a cheap router. Login to the admin dashboard and setup what ever WiFi security settings you want to attack. The device doesn't even need to be connected to the internet or your network.

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy, I didn't even know that it wasn't necessary to connect it to internet.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, you have to practice breaking into wifi authentications.

For this, you either need to setup your own access point or try breaking into someone else' with their prior permission.

How are you planning to do it anyways ? is upto you.